# auto increment not starting from 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am inserting some data to a database and I have an id column which has auto increment. I updated my xampp server yesterday and now the auto increment is starting from 4, 3, 5 in different tables. It used to work fine before. I did not delete any rows from the table it just starts from those numbers. What is wrong?

Comment: You can reset it: `ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Comment: There is nothing wrong. You _should not care what the numbers are_. You requested autonumbering, don't hang any functionality on the value of that number, just use them as identifiers. That aside, you can reset an auto_increment number to where you like, but this is not the point. **There is no problem**

Comment: Okay if I shouldn't be worried about it. Thanks

Comment: Huge problem,now you have billions - 3 rows,you are about to run out of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to reset this, in phpMyAdmin, open this table, go to Operations and change the value for AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Please give more details: table's structure, MySQL version.

Comment: wow I'm in touch with phpmyadmin creator :D It's doesn't metter anyway

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

This will reset your auto increment to start from 1

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your auto increment ID from the following Command:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

This will start from 1.

OR
go to LOCALHOST/PHPMYADMIN enter:

```
select your DB
```

after choose the specific table than go to Operations an set a number to the Auto increment.

Comment: Also use this:

DELETE FROM table;
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to reset this, in phpMyAdmin, open this table, go to Operations and change the value for AUTO_INCREMENT.----- this is working for me, i have just done this,

Answer (score 0):

This can be a consequence of using a Galera cluster. By [default](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_auto_increment_control), it will automatically adjust the `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` variables according to the size of the cluster, and when the cluster size changes. This avoids replication conflicts due to auto_increment.

The short answer is not to depend on `auto_increment` numbers being subsequent, without gaps.